# On the Uri object, can the original string property ever be null?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to construct the Uri object in such a way that it has a null original string?

I.e. Is the `Uri myUri.OriginalString != null` check worthy?

The MSDN for [OriginalString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.uri.originalstring) notes that:

An `InvalidOperationException` is possible if *This instance represents a relative URI, and this property is valid only for absolute URIs.* However I haven't been able to trip this.

`new Uri("~/SignIn", UriKind.Relative)` seems to work OK for OriginalString.

Comment: Can you add a few more tags or some context?

Comment: If unsure, I usually just do the check. Better safe than sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.uri.originalstring says this property contains the exact URI specified when this instance was constructed; otherwise, Empty.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z6c2z492 specifies Uri can't be constructed with null string.

So, you need not check against null. But you may want to check against String.Empty though.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492.aspx) : an `ArgumentNullException` is thrown at construction if the Url string is `null` (also if it is empty, ill-formed etc..).

So the check is not needed.

Comment: Wow, that was fast :) - see edit, apparently an InvalidOperationException is possible, but I can't work out how to trip it.

Comment: yes, that is possible. But still, OriginalString will never be null